# Returning a locally defined array of strings from a function produces memory error

Tags: c

I'm struggling for days with a school assignment in c. The task is to write a function which accepts an array of strings and it's length, then checks the length of the shortest string in the array and finally collects the strings whose lenghts are equal to the shortest length in the passed array. The main function is given and expected to be written well, it only passes the array of strings, calls the function then loops through the returned array to print it's contents. The main() uses a tmp pointer and it is also unclear to me, why that is necessary, it would be also appreciated if someone could shed some light on that one.

So my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **foo(char **t, int size){

  int i;
  int current_length;
  int shortest_length = strlen(t[0]);
  int num_of_shortest = 0;


  //define shortest string length
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    current_length = strlen(t[i]);

    if(shortest_length > current_length)
      shortest_length = current_length;
  }
  //define the number of the shortest strings
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    current_length = strlen(t[i]);

    if(shortest_length == current_length)
      num_of_shortest++;
  }
  //define an array, to hold the shortest things in order of appearance in the passed array of strings
  static char **array_of_shortests;
  array_of_shortests = malloc(sizeof(char)*num_of_shortest);


  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    current_length = strlen(t[i]);
    //allocate memory for the string stored in the array of shortest strings
    array_of_shortests[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(t[i])+1);

    //fill up the array of the shortest strings
    if(shortest_length == current_length)
    {
      array_of_shortests[i] = t[i];
    }
  }


  return array_of_shortests;
}


int main()
{
    char *t[] = {"apple", "pineapple", "orange", "apple", "banana", "grape"};
    char **result = foo(t, sizeof(t) / sizeof(char *));
    char **tmp;
    for (tmp = result; *tmp; ++tmp)
        printf("%s\n", *tmp);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles well, but then produces the folowing error when run:

```
[root@berlin tmp]# gcc -o practice_shortest_strings practice_shortest_strings.c
[root@berlin tmp]# ./practice_shortest_strings
apple


apple

grape
*** Error in `./practice_shortest_strings': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000809010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c503)[0x7f88d95e0503]
./practice_shortest_strings[0x40081d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f88d9585b35]
./practice_shortest_strings[0x400549]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 100943188                          /tmp/practice_shortest_strings
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 100943188                          /tmp/practice_shortest_strings
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 100943188                          /tmp/practice_shortest_strings
00809000-0082a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f88d4000000-7f88d4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f88d4021000-7f88d8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f88d934e000-7f88d9363000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 69263259                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f88d9363000-7f88d9562000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 69263259                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f88d9562000-7f88d9563000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 69263259                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f88d9563000-7f88d9564000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 69263259                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f88d9564000-7f88d971a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 67658381                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f88d971a000-7f88d991a000 ---p 001b6000 fd:00 67658381                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f88d991a000-7f88d991e000 r--p 001b6000 fd:00 67658381                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f88d991e000-7f88d9920000 rw-p 001ba000 fd:00 67658381                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f88d9920000-7f88d9925000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f88d9925000-7f88d9945000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 67149962                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f88d9b37000-7f88d9b3a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f88d9b41000-7f88d9b44000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f88d9b44000-7f88d9b45000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 67149962                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f88d9b45000-7f88d9b46000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 67149962                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f88d9b46000-7f88d9b47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffdfbf81000-7ffdfbfa2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffdfbfbb000-7ffdfbfbd000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Please help me out here, I'm out of ideas... Tanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Since you return a pointer that you allocate, you don't have to declare the variable `static`. Returning pointers is okay, because the memory it points to is not local to the function. The problem is that you don't allocate enough memory. Hint: `sizeof(char) != sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: First 'for' loop; should > be <

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc): 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned value type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: this code block: `if(shortest_length == current_length)
        {
            array_of_shortests[i] = listOfArrays[i];
        }` only copies a pointer, not the contents of the `t[i]` array entry.

Comment: To add to what @Someprogrammerdude wrote above, (which is surely correct:), be very wary of static storage - it's not thread-safe:(

Answer (score 0):

The posted code contains several problems.  See the comments to the question for the details.

The following, proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. uses meaningful parameter and variable names
3. the sub function name: `foo()` is terrible and it gives no indication of what the function does.  If there was a choice, I prefer: `selectShortestStrings()`
4. uses `calloc()` rather than `malloc()` so memory is pre-initialized to all NULL
5. allows for the possibility that all strings are of the same length
6. properly checks for error indications being returned from system functions
7. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
8. consistently indents the code.  Indents after every opening brace '{', unindents before every closing brace '}'. uses 4 spaces for each indent level
9. separates code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.
10. separates each function by 2 blank lines.
11. uses `size_t` rather than `int` to avoid 'implicit conversions'
12. did not modify the `main()` function
    although the signature should be: `int main( void )`
    and readability would be greatly enhanced with a meaningful sub function name, separation of code blocks, and similar modifications
13. uses `lowerCamelCase` for ease of readability of variable names and consistency.
14. includes documentation of why each header file was included
15. places the sub function `foo()` after `main()` so reading through the code progresses downward rather than jumping back upward.
16. localized the scope of the variable `i` in each code block where it is used.

definition of `lowerCamelCase:

lowerCamelCase (part of CamelCase) is a naming convention in which a name is formed of multiple words that are joined together as a single word with the first letter of each of the multiple words (except the first one) capitalized within the new word that forms the name.

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf()
#include <stdlib.h>   // calloc(), free(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>   // strlen()

// prototypes
char **foo( char **, size_t );





int main()
{
    char *t[] = {"apple", "pineapple", "orange", "apple", "banana", "grape"};
    char **result = foo(t, sizeof(t) / sizeof(char *));
    char **tmp;
    for (tmp = result; *tmp; ++tmp)
        printf("%s\n", *tmp);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}


char **foo( char **stringPtrs, size_t size )
{
    // using 'size_t' because 'strlen()' returns a 'size_t'
    size_t currentLength;
    size_t shortestaLength = strlen(stringPtrs[0]);
    size_t numOfShortest = 0;


    //define shortest string length
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        currentLength = strlen( stringPtrs[i]);

        if(shortestaLength > currentLength)
          shortestaLength = currentLength;
    }

    //define the number of the shortest strings
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        currentLength = strlen(stringPtrs[i]);

        if(shortestaLength == currentLength)
          numOfShortest++;
    }

    // define an array, to hold the pointer to the shortest things
    // in order of appearance in the passed array of strings
    char **shortestPtrs = NULL;

    // note printing loop in main() checks for NULL pointer
    // so, just incase all the entries are the same length
    // allocate room for extra entry and set all to NULL
    shortestPtrs = calloc(numOfShortest+1, sizeof( char* ));
    if( !shortestPtrs )
    {
        perror( "calloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, calloc successful

    // cannot have NULL pointer in middle of array
    // so indexing of output has to be separate from index of input
    size_t shortestIndex = 0;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        currentLength = strlen(stringPtrs[i]);

        //fill up the array of the shortest strings
        if(shortestaLength == currentLength)
        {
            shortestPtrs[ shortestIndex ] = stringPtrs[i];
            shortestIndex++;
        }
    }

    return shortestPtrs;
} // end function: foo
```

the resulting output is:

```
apple
apple
grape
```

Comment: Most C style guides explicitly discourage the use of `lowerCamelCase` of `CamelCase` in favor of reserving upper-case for use with *constants* or *macros* while using all lower-case for *variable* and *function* names. C++ and java make use of the `MixedCase` and `camelCase` names. It's style, so it's up to you, but there are general norms.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,  I've been working software contracts for over 40 years (with the last ~30 years almost exclusively C).  In every software contract that uses C, where the client has stated a preference, they wanted lowerCamelCase With macro names and `enum` names being all upper case and using underscores to separate root words,  I.E. they specifically forbid all lower case with underscores for variable and function names.  Usually the client has an extensive list of 'industry' abbreviations that they want all upper case.  Given my experience, lowerCamelCase is what I advocate.

Comment: Well I too, I started maintaining SVDS for the Shuttle Program w/RSOC at JSC in the late 80's and was there for the port to C done by McDonnell Douglass and was there for the comparison and documentation of the standard C styles ([**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf)) I don't doubt there are some clients that want something different, but that doesn't make what they want the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You have two primary problems in your code. First your allocation for `array_of_shortests` allocates `num_of_shortest` (characters) instead of `num_of_shortest` (pointers) -- resulting in an under-allocation by a factor of `sizeof (a pointer)` for your architecture (`8` on x86_64). You can correct it as follows while validating the allocation and setting the last *sentinel* pointer to `NULL`:

```
/* define an array of pointer to holding the address to the shortest
 * strings in order of appearance in the passed array of strings
 */
if (!(array_of_shortests = 
        malloc (sizeof *array_of_shortests * (num_of_shortest + 1))))
    return NULL;

array_of_shortests[num_of_shortest] = NULL; /* set sentinel NULL */
```

Your next error(s) are (1) the unnecessary allocation of storage for each string in `array_of_shortests`, (2) improperly indexing `array_of_shortests[i]`, and (3) failing to free the memory you allocate for each string before calling `free (result)` to free the pointers in `main`.

Since the strings in `array_of_shortests` already have adequate storage as *string literals* referenced by `t`, all you care about is pointing to the addresses of the shortest literals and storing the pointer address in `array_of_shortests` (you don't need to allocate memory to copy/store the string literals again). You simply need to allocate `num_of_shortest + 1`, which you have already done above (the `+1` to provide space for your *sentinel NULL*, for the iteration scheme you use back in `main`), then assign the address of each shortest to e.g. `array_of_shortests[ndx++]`:

```
int i,
    ndx = 0,
    ...
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    current_length = strlen (t[i]);
    /* you allocated 'pointers' no need to allocate storage for each,
     * the pointers can hold the address of the shortest in 't'.
     * NOTE: you cannot use array_of_shortests[i]
     */
    if (current_length == shortest_length)
        array_of_shortests[ndx++] = t[i];
}
```

Then back in `main` you can iterate over, print and `free` the pointers as you have done. Putting the pieces together, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **foo (char **t, int size) {

    /* valdiate parameters - minimally */
    if (!t || !*t || size < 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "foo() error: invalid paramater.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char **array_of_shortests = NULL;
    int i,
        ndx = 0,
        current_length,
        shortest_length = strlen (t[0]),
        num_of_shortest = 0;

    /* define shortest string length */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        current_length = strlen (t[i]);

        if (current_length < shortest_length)
            shortest_length = current_length;
    }

    /* define the number of the shortest strings */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        current_length = strlen (t[i]);

        if (shortest_length == current_length)
            num_of_shortest++;
    }

    /* define an array of pointer to holding the address to the shortest
     * strings in order of appearance in the passed array of strings
     */
    if (!(array_of_shortests = 
            malloc (sizeof *array_of_shortests * (num_of_shortest + 1))))
        return NULL;

    array_of_shortests[num_of_shortest] = NULL; /* set sentinel NULL */

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        current_length = strlen (t[i]);
        /* you allocated 'pointers' no need to allocate storage for each,
         * the pointers can hold the address of the shortest in 't'.
         * NOTE: you cannot use array_of_shortests[i]
         */
        if (current_length == shortest_length)
            array_of_shortests[ndx++] = t[i];
    }

    return array_of_shortests;
}

int main (void) {

    char *t[] = { "apple", "pineapple", "orange", 
                  "apple", "banana", "grape" },
        **result = foo (t, sizeof t / sizeof *t),
        **tmp = result;

    if (!result) {
        fprintf (stderr, "foo() error: result is NULL.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (*tmp)
        printf ("%s\n", *tmp++);

    free (result);  /* free array of pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/shorteststrs
apple
apple
grape
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/shorteststrs
==23647== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23647== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23647== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23647== Command: ./bin/shorteststrs
==23647==
apple
apple
grape
==23647==
==23647== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23647==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23647==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==23647==
==23647== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==23647==
==23647== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23647== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

**Passing a Pointer to** `num_of_shortest` **Instead of Using Sentinel**

While there is nothing wrong with adding an additional pointer to `array_of_shortests` and setting it to `NULL`, your other option is to declare `num_of_shortest` back in `main` and simply pass, and update, a pointer within `foo`. This provides a way to make `num_of_shortest` available back in `main`. E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **foo (char **t, int size, int *num_of_shortest) {

    /* valdiate parameters - minimally */
    if (!t || !*t || size < 1 || !num_of_shortest) {
        fprintf (stderr, "foo() error: invalid paramater.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char **array_of_shortests = NULL;
    int i,
        ndx = 0,
        current_length,
        shortest_length = strlen (t[0]);

    *num_of_shortest = 0;

    /* define shortest string length */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        current_length = strlen (t[i]);

        if (current_length < shortest_length)
            shortest_length = current_length;
    }

    /* define the number of the shortest strings */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        current_length = strlen (t[i]);

        if (shortest_length == current_length)
            (*num_of_shortest)++;
    }

    /* define an array of pointer to holding the address to the shortest
     * strings in order of appearance in the passed array of strings
     */
    if (!(array_of_shortests =
            malloc (sizeof *array_of_shortests * *num_of_shortest)))
        return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        current_length = strlen (t[i]);
        /* you allocated 'pointers' no need to allocate storage for each,
         * the pointers can hold the address of the shortest in 't'.
         * NOTE: you cannot use array_of_shortests[i]
         */
        if (current_length == shortest_length)
            array_of_shortests[ndx++] = t[i];
    }

    return array_of_shortests;
}

int main (void) {

    int i, n = 0;   /* pass address of n to foo */
    char *t[] = { "apple", "pineapple", "orange",
                  "apple", "banana", "grape" },
        **result = foo (t, sizeof t / sizeof *t, &n);

    if (!result) {
        fprintf (stderr, "foo() error: result is NULL.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%s\n", result[i]);

    free (result);  /* free array of pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/shortest
apple
apple
grape
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/shortest
==23565== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23565== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23565== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23565== Command: ./bin/shortest
==23565==
apple
apple
grape
==23565==
==23565== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23565==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23565==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==23565==
==23565== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==23565==
==23565== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23565== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Note:** you save "a pointer" in allocation (which is insignificant, but notable).

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.